# why using rand() without setting seed with srand() some numbers change?

Tags: c, random, mpi

I'm generating random numbers with rand() bounded to 1000 with this little piece of code:

> `for(int i=0;i<pARRAYSIZE;i++) pARRAY[i] = rand()%MAX_VALUE_DATA;`

(I'm NOT using srand() function, so by default seed would be 1? [1])

Sometimes I get this sequence:

> 362 , 27  , 690 , 59  , 763 , 926 , 540 , 426 ,
> 172 , 736 , 211 , 368 , 567 , 429 , 782 , 530 ,
> 862 , 123 , 67  , 135 , 929 , 802 , 22  , 58  ,
> 69  , 167 , 393 , 456 , 11  , 42  , 229 , 373 ,
> 421 , 919 , 784 , 537 , 198 , 324 , 315 , 370 ,
> 413 , 526 , 91  , 980 , 956 , 873 , 862 , 170 ,
> 996 , 281 , 305 , 925 , 84  , 327 , 336 , 505 ,
> 846 , 729 , 313 , 857 , 124 , 895 , 582 , 545 ,  ...

And sometimes I get this other sequence:

> 27  , 690 , 59  , 763 , 926 , 540 , 426 , 172 ,
> 736 , 211 , 368 , 567 , 429 , 782 , 530 , 862 ,
> 123 , 67  , 135 , 929 , 802 , 22  , 58  , 69  ,
> 167 , 393 , 456 , 11  , 42  , 229 , 373 , 421 ,
> 919 , 784 , 537 , 198 , 324 , 315 , 370 , 413 ,
> 526 , 91  , 980 , 956 , 873 , 862 , 170 , 996 ,
> 281 , 305 , 925 , 84  , 327 , 336 , 505 , 846 ,
> 729 , 313 , 857 , 124 , 895 , 582 , 545 , 814 , ...

Which is the same as the first one but with 362 at the start (the real squence have a size of 1024 numbers, when 362 don't exist it generates a 871 in a fixed position of the array to complete the 1024 numbers).

And in a relly few cases it generates this other sequence which is the second one without 27, 690 and 59:

> 763 , 926 , 540 , 426 , 172 , 736 , 211 , 368 ,
> 567 , 429 , 782 , 530 , 862 , 123 , 67  , 135 ,
> 929 , 802 , 22  , 58  , 69  , 167 , 393 , 456 ,
> 11  , 42  , 229 , 373 , 421 , 919 , 784 , 537 ,
> 198 , 324 , 315 , 370 , 413 , 526 , 91  , 980 ,
> 956 , 873 , 862 , 170 , 996 , 281 , 305 , 925 ,
> 84  , 327 , 336 , 505 , 846 , 729 , 313 , 857 ,
> 124 , 895 , 582 , 545 , 814 , 367 , 434 , 364 , ...

[1] Some test I did: if I force the seed to be 1 with srand(1) I **always** get the following sequence:

> 383 , 886 , 777 , 915 , 793 , 335 , 386 , 492 ,
> 649 , 421 , 362 , 27  , 690 , 59  , 763 , 926 ,
> 540 , 426 , 172 , 736 , 211 , 368 , 567 , 429 ,
> 782 , 530 , 862 , 123 , 67  , 135 , 929 , 802 ,
> 22  , 58  , 69  , 167 , 393 , 456 , 11  , 42  ,
> 229 , 373 , 421 , 919 , 784 , 537 , 198 , 324 ,
> 315 , 370 , 413 , 526 , 91  , 980 , 956 , 873 ,
> 862 , 170 , 996 , 281 , 305 , 925 , 84  , 327 , ...

Edit: without using srand() I got a new sequence, which is similar to the second one but without 27...

> 690 , 59  , 763 , 926 , 540 , 426 , 172 , 736 ,
> 211 , 368 , 567 , 429 , 782 , 530 , 862 , 123 ,
> 67  , 135 , 929 , 802 , 22  , 58  , 69  , 167 ,
> 393 , 456 , 11  , 42  , 229 , 373 , 421 , 919 ,
> 784 , 537 , 198 , 324 , 315 , 370 , 413 , 526 ,
> 91  , 980 , 956 , 873 , 862 , 170 , 996 , 281 ,
> 305 , 925 , 84  , 327 , 336 , 505 , 846 , 729 ,
> 313 , 857 , 124 , 895 , 582 , 545 , 814 , 367 , ...

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void initVector(int *pARRAY, int pARRAYSIZE) {
    for(int i=0;i<pARRAYSIZE;i++) pARRAY[i] = rand()%1000;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int rank, nrProcesos;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nrProcesos); 

    int *E = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 1024);

    if (rank==0)
    {
        //srand(1);
        initVector(E, 1024);
    }

    #ifdef DEBUG
        if(rank == 0){
            for(int i=0;i<1024;i++){
                if(i%8==0) printf("\n");
                printf("%-4d, ", E[i]);
            } printf("\n");
        }
    #endif //DEBUG

    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return(0); 
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
mpicc -DDEBUG -o stackoverflow stackoverflow.c
mpirun --bind-to none -np 4 stackoverflow
```

I "solved" it by calling the `srand(1)`  (at least I hope...), but I'm still curious why does that happen.

Comment: probably some bug with the rand() implementation?

Comment: More likely some bug in the code you haven't shown us. See [mcve].

Comment: Also state which compiler / version / flags you're using.

Comment: @dbush Edited! I just put how I compile it

Comment: Umm yeah, it's a pretty safe bet that this has nothing to do with `rand` or `srand` (other than they're probably not thread safe), and everything to do with MPI. I've added the MPI tag for you.

Comment: `rand()` is likely invoked by MPI or its dependencies.

Comment: What happens if you omit the MPI calls (and don't use the `mpicc` and `mpirun` commands but simply use the C compiler directly)?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I **always** get the "383 , 886 , 777 , 915 , 793 , 335, ..." (the one I mentioned in [1]). I asume then this is a MPI problem, maybe like Gilles Gouaillardet said, rand() is being invoked by MPI lib? Edit: I compiled with "gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)" `gcc -DDEBUG -o stackoverflow stackoverflow.c`

Comment: It does appear that MPI is dinking with random numbers somewhere along the line, though that's somewhat uncivilized behaviour in many ways — library code should not ordinarily use `rand()` precisely because doing so messes up the sequences that users would otherwise expect.  However, there's also an argument that you should always set a seed with `srand()`, but I'm not wholly convinced.